# opengl 3.3 / glew 1.9 VBO support returns false

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo, glew

I've built an simple OpenGL window and checked it's support. The support it returned:

- GLEW: 1.9.0
- OpenGL: 3.3.0

The problem I'm having is due creating shapes (VBO). While creating a shape based off of a tutorial, I couldn't get the image (a simple triangle) to display to the screen. The only way other way was achieve this was using Immediate Mode or a basic Vertex Array.

I inquired on checking vbo support with GLEW, but all of the suggestions I've found such as:

```
if ( glewGetExtension("GL_VERSION_1_9") 
    && glewGetExtension( "GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object" ))
        {
            std::cout << "VBO supported." << std::endl;
        }
    else
        {
            std::cerr << "ARB_vertex_buffer_object not supported!" << std::endl;
        }
```

returned false.

Any suggestions as to what may be the problem?

Comment: If you are using the core functions (not ARB), just checking for OpenGL 1.5 (like `if (!GLEW_VERSION_1_5) { error(); }`) should be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out why I was getting errors. The problem was I was checking glew BEFORE creating the window. So I after adding the condition AFTER the window was created, everything started to work as it should. Just in case someone runs into this problem, call `glewInit()` after creating the window.

Answer (score 1):

Stop checking for `ARB_vertex_buffer_object`. In fact, stop *using* ARB_vertex_buffer_object. Use [the *core* functionality](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object), not the extension functionality. If you're asking for OpenGL version 3.3, then you *have* buffer object functionality in core. Use that.

```
glewGetExtension("GL_VERSION_1_9")
```

There is no such extension. There is also no OpenGL version 1.9, so I have no idea why you would check it that way.

If you want to check for an OpenGL version, you should [use the OpenGL functionality](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Get_Context_Info#OpenGL_version_number) for doing that:

```
GLint major = 0;
GLint minor = 0;
glGetIntegerv​(GL_MAJOR_VERSION​, &major);
glGetIntegerv​(GL_MINOR_VERSION​, &minor);
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but that didn't help to check if VBOs are supported or not. Plus glGetIntegerv is not defined (error i received).

Comment: @SpicyWeenie: If *`glGetIntegerv`* is "not defined", you have serious problems in your code. That means you can't find even basic GL 1.1 functions.